# post xml data in ajax using javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, post

**I am sending some xml data with url. it just posting**

```
$.ajax({
    url                 : _url,
    type                : "post",
    contentType     : "text/xml",
    dataType            : "json",
    error               : function( xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError ){ 
                                console.info( "Error" ); 
                                console.info( "xhr" , xhr );
                                console.info( "ajaxOptions", ajaxOptions );
                                console.info( "thrownError ", thrownError  );
                            },
    success         : function( response ){

                    console.info( "response" , response );

    }

});
```

escap xml is also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's so easy. You should try searching more.
See here :

```
var fd = new FormData();    
fd.append( 'aSetValue', aXml );   

$.ajax({
 url     : _url,
 type    : "post",
 data    : fd,
 processData: false,
 contentType: false,   
 dataType   : "json",
 error    : function( xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError ){ 
      console.info( "Error" ); 
      console.info( "xhr" , xhr );
      console.info( "ajaxOptions", ajaxOptions );
      console.info( "thrownError ", thrownError  );
     },
 success   : function( response ){

   console.info( "response" , response );

 }

});
```

Comment: What is fd? What did you fix? I mean, how did you guess what the problem is, because there is just no explanation. We have no idea what the error is and why it's not working.

Comment: Hey Jeremy, we are trying to post xml using the ajax. but it's posting data.  and in this answer we first convert this by FormData.

Comment: I have faced that issue earlier when was trying to pass the XML. May be he was doing the same mistake of not creating formData and passing directly XML in that. I just created a variable to have the FormData of the XML to be passed.